# Complete open source software stack which can be used for building digital twins?

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, ontology, eclipse-digital-twin

For a poc project, we would like to build digital twin of an physical device like e.g. coffee machine. Would like to know which open source software components can be used for the same. Some software components based on the information available are mentioned below:

1. Eclipse Hono IOT platform for iot gateway
2. Eclipse Vorto for describing information models
3. Eclipse Ditto for Digital Twin representation. It provides abstract representation of device last state in the form of http or websocket apis
4. Blender  / Unreal Engine for 3D models
5. Protege for Ontology editor

I have the following questions:

1. Are we missing any software components to create digital twin of an physical asset?
2. Assuming we have 3D models available and sensor data is also available, how can we feed live sensor data to 3D models e.g changing the color of water tank based on real sensor data of water tank level? Not able to understand how real time sensor data will be connected to 3D models.
3. How will ontology be helpful in creating 3D models?

Comment: This question seems too broad; try focusing on one question and remember to review the [help] on what kinds of questions are on-topic at Stack Overflow (read: programming ones, specifically, not high-level software design ones).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a 3d model and sensor information, and you want to change some properties of the 3d model to reflect the sensor information? You should need to use 5 different tools for something like that. I would suggest looking into video games development tools like Unity3D or UnrealEngine 4.